# Google Docs embed answering form

Tags: google-docs

I want to embed a form in an email that works both in a web browser and the gmail app, using google docs. 
I have been able to embed it and use it in different browsers with the following code, but I can't use it in the app. 
The problem is that I want the user to respond by ticking either Yes or No, and clicking an Accept button.

Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance

```
 form.setRequireLogin(false);
   var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).getContent();
   MailApp.sendEmail(responsableDirecto,
                "Course request",
                "",
                {
                  name: 'Course request confirmation'+""+program+""+name,
                  htmlBody: htmlBody,
                  attachments: [documetoDatos],
                });
```

Comment: The problem is that the gmail app has limited html formatting options and strips the css in header in the name of optimisation. So usually the only option remains is to open the link in the browser. Or possible workarounds are by manipulating the html in the form and sending the mail .